# JetBrains Rider large tool-tip appearing

Tags: tooltip, jetbrains-ide, rider

I have a problem with a tool-tip that appears it seems as a helper for function/method parameters, it takes up a large amount of the screen and can only be turned off by clicking enter, which is causing a large annoyance.

Does anyone know how do I turn this off permanently?

[image: https://i.imgur.com/ogkHTPY.png]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change it by toggling the following setting:

> File | Settings | Editor | General | Code Completion | Show the parameter info popup

Comment: Do you know how I can turn this off in the settings but invoke it with a key press? i.e. Most times I don't want it to appear, but occasionally I need to look up what overloads are available.